# Energy of explicit euler

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, proof-writing

In their studies about the heat equation, my supervisor and his peers always calculate the energy of the explicit euler scheme using the formula:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\Delta x}{2}\sum(\upsilon_j^m)^2
\end{equation}
where $\Delta x$ is the grid spacing in the x-direction, and $\upsilon_j^m$ denotes an approximation of $u(x_j, t_m)$.

My question is: **how do I prove this formula?**

In case it is important, I am talking about the partial differential equation:
\begin{equation}
  u_t = u_{xx}
\end{equation}
subject to the boundary conditions:
\begin{equation}
  u(0, t) = u(l, t) = 0, t > 0
\end{equation}
and the initial condition:
\begin{equation}
  u(x, 0) = f(x), x \in (0, l)
\end{equation}

I know the energy formula comes somehow from the scheme:
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\upsilon_j^{m + 1} - \upsilon_j^m}{\Delta t} = \frac{\upsilon_{j - 1}^m - 2\upsilon_j^m + \upsilon_{j + 1}^m}{\Delta x^2} \text{, for } j = 1, ..., n \text{ and } m \geq 0.
\end{equation}

But how should I proceed to prove it? I really have no clue, and my supervisor always avoids answering this question.

Comment: $u$ is a conserved quantity if you use Neumann boundary condition. And $\int dx \, u_x u_x$ is the energy if it is a Hamiltonian system. I don't know the context of what energy means in your problem.

Comment: @anecdote It is a Dirichlet boundary condition, and this energy is used to derive certain properties of the solution of a differential equation without knowing the solution in detail. It is not necessarily the physical energy.

Comment: I can't prove $\int u^2 dx $ is the "energy", without knowing what you mean by "energy". Please elaborate on how this quantity gives you information about the equation, and perhaps what we should think about is why it is called "energy" given its property.

Comment: I am not sure why it is called energy, but we can plot a exponential decay chart from this formula. This formula also gives us information about the numerical scheme, like the rate of convergence and numerical error.

Comment: I never really found a source using this energy to get information about the analytical solution. I am just citing a book by Tveito, called "Introduction to Partial Differential Equations". Tveito says that this energy can derive properties similar to the maximum principles. I am sorry if I am not explaining enough about it. Usually I only use this energy to calculate the rate of convergence and numerical error of the numerical scheme, so I am not 100% sure about any other properties.

Comment: @anecdote I was reading the source again, and Tveito actually calls it "energy arguments". He uses the integral $E(t)=\int_0^lu^2(x,t)dx$, but never explains why.

Comment: I see. Its derivative is (minus) the Hamiltonian, which is always negative, and hence it can be used to control stability.

Comment: Could you please quote some relevant part of the text in the question? This question do not very few attention because not everybody have access to Tveito's book and understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "energy argument" used in Tveito's book "Introduction to Partial Differential Equations" is a quantity that is non-negative and non-increasing during the evolution. It therefore can be used to analyze the stability of the numerical scheme. And it's usually independent of the detailed form of the solution. I'm trying to explain its relation to what I think can be reasonably called energy.

***Wave Equation***

The wave equation is the saddle point of the energy functional. Let
\begin{equation}
E[ u] = \int dx dt\,  (  u_x^2 + u_t^2  )
\end{equation}
the saddle point lies at
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta E[u]}{\delta u} = -2 ( u_{xx} + u_{tt} ) = 0
\end{equation}
So the energy is conserved.

In fact, $E[u]$ is the physical energy of the vibrating string.

***Heat Equation***

The parabolic equation can be understood as a dissipative process towards some equilibrium state($u_t = 0$). After all, if the process itself is unstable(exponential growth), how can we possibly have a stable numerical scheme?

So usually, the evolution of $u$ is going towards the minimal of some energy functional
\begin{equation}
u_t = - \frac{\delta E}{\delta u}
\end{equation}
The minus sign points to the minus of the gradient of the non-negative energy functional such that the process always decreases the energy(gradient descent).

The time derivative of "energy argument" used in Tveito's book is
\begin{equation}
\int (u u_t) \, dx  = - \int  (\frac{\delta E}{\delta u} u )\, dx 
\end{equation}
If the equation is linear, then $E[u]$ is quadratic; we usually have 
\begin{equation}
\int (\frac{\delta E}{ u} u) \, dx = 2 E[u]
\end{equation}
For example, if
\begin{equation}
E[u] = \frac{1}{2} \int \left[(u_x)^2 + u^2 \right] \, dx
\end{equation}
then 
\begin{equation}
\int  \frac{\delta E}{\delta u} u  dx  = \int \left[(- u_{xx} + u ) u  \right] \,dx =  \int \left[(u_x)^2 + u^2  \right] \,dx = 2 E[u]
\end{equation}
Following the assumption that $E[u]$ is semi-positive definite, we successfully constructed a quantity that is bounded and never increasing. Since it's related to energy functional that generate this process, we can fairly call it "energy argument". This can be applied to a wide range of problems so long as the energy functional is semi-positive definite.

Otherwise, one need to work out some properties of the solution. For example equation (11.26) of the book
\begin{equation}
u_t = u_{xx} + u(1-u)
\end{equation}
is generated by the energy function
\begin{equation}
E[u] =  \int dx \, \left[\frac{1}{2} ( u_x)^2 - \frac{1}{2} u^2  + \frac{1}{3} u^3 \right]
\end{equation}
which is not positive definite. And then it is not easy to construct such bounded decreasing "energy argument" without knowing some properties of the solution. The author therefore spends the next section trying to bound the solution and then construct and prove the "energy arguments". In this case the "energy argument" may very well be distinct from the energy functional.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it all makes sense.